# Heat Equation Solution Dependence on Diffusion Coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given a heat equation of $u$ with spatial dependent diffusion coefficient $\alpha(x)\ge 0$
$$\frac{\partial u_\alpha}{\partial t}=\alpha(x) \frac{\partial^2 u_\alpha}{\partial x^2}$$
where $(t,x)\in [0,T]\times[0,1]$, $u_\alpha(0,x)$ is a positive concave function, and $u_\alpha(t,0)=u_\alpha(t,1)=0$. If $\alpha(x)<\beta(x), \forall x\in [0,1]$, is it true that $u_\alpha(t,x)>u_\beta(t,x)$, $\forall t>0, x\in (0,1)$?

---

I now realize the answer to the last question is in the negative. Consider $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are interspersed with intervals with zero value.

Comment: Can you prove that $u_\beta(t,\cdot)$ remains positive and concave? If yes, then consider the equation that is satisfied by $u_\alpha - u_\beta$.

Comment: @HansEngler: The positivity of $u_\alpha$ comes directly from the maximum principle. The concavity is preserved had $\alpha$ been constant. The concavity could not be preserved under general $\alpha(x)$. Think of $\alpha(x)$ interspersed with intervals of vanishing value. I have considered the route of $u_\alpha-u_\beta$, which succeeds when $\alpha$ is constant. What to do with $x$ dependent $\alpha$?

Comment: @HansEngler: I edited my question after some thoughts. Please check it out.

Comment: this appears to be difficult. Have you looked at W. Walter's book?

Comment: @HansEngler: Do you agree with my assertion, a rough description of a counterexample, at the bottom of my question? Can you give the title of the book and the full name of W. Walter you mentioned?

Comment: Nick Korevaar (Indiana Univ. Math. J. 1983) introduces a "concavity function" and proves a maximum principle for it. These results apply to heat equations such as the ones in the question and imply that solutions with concave initial data remain concave, at least for certain boundary conditions. While I haven't checked if  this applies to zero Dirichlet data, this should still shed light on the question. (I should have remembered this result - I was in the audience when he presented it as a postdoc in 1982).

Comment: Here is the bibtex entry for the book by W. Walter: @book{walter1970differential,
  title={Differential and integral inequalities},
  author={Walter, Wolfgang},
  year={1970},
  publisher={Springer}
}

Comment: @HansEngler: Are you sure Nick Korevaar's result, I have yet to get hold of --- would you happen to have a full title of the paper? --- applies to $\alpha(x)$ rather than a constant $\alpha$? You do not agree with my counterexample on the non-preservation of concavity? Does Korevaar have a different definition for the concave function then the usual one?

Comment: @HansEngler: Thank you for the reference to W. Walter's book. Would you be so kind as to narrow down the relevant chapter? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22288/discussion-between-hans-and-hans-engler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that $u_\alpha > u_\beta$ for $t > 0, 0 < x < 1$.

Consider first the problem
$$
\partial_t u = \gamma(x) \partial^2_x u, \, 0 < x < 1, \, u(0) = u(1) = 1 \, .
$$
with smooth $\gamma$ that is positive on $[0,1]$.

**Lemma.** If $u(0,\cdot)$ is concave, then $\partial^2_x u(t, \cdot) \le 0$ for all $t > 0$.

**Proof.** Without loss of generality, $u(0,\cdot)$ is smooth. Set $w = \partial^2_x u$. Then $w(0,\cdot) \le 0$ and  $w$ satisfies
$$
\partial_t w = \gamma(x)\partial^2_x w + 2\gamma'(x) \partial_x w + \gamma''(x)w 
$$
Also, for $x \in \{0,1\}$, we know that $\gamma(x) w(t,x) = \gamma(x) \partial_t u(t,x) = \gamma(x) \cdot 0 = 0$ and thus $w(t,x) = 0$ for $x \in \{0,1\}$. By the usual comparison principle for solutions of parabolic equations, $u_{xx}(t,x) = w(\cdot,  x) \le 0$ for $t > 0, \, 0 < x < 1$.

Now consider the two problem 
$$
\partial_t u_\alpha = \alpha(x) \partial^2_x u_\alpha, \quad
\partial_t u_\beta = \beta(x) \partial^2_x u_\beta
$$
with $\alpha < \beta$ on $[0,1]$. Also assume that $\alpha, \beta$ are both continuous. Find a smooth $\gamma$ such that $\alpha < \gamma < \beta$. Let $u_\gamma$ the solution of the heat equation with this coefficient function and set $v = u_\alpha - u_\gamma$, with the same initial and boundary data. Then $v$ satisfies
$$
\partial_t v = \alpha(x) \partial^2_x v + (\alpha(x) - \gamma(x)) \partial^2_x u_\gamma
$$
with data $v(0,x) = 0, \, v(t,0) = v(t,1) = 0$. Since $\partial^2_x u_\gamma \le 0$ and $\alpha - \gamma > 0$, it follows that $v > 0$ for $t > 0, \, 0 < x < 1$. Thus $u_\alpha > u_\gamma$ in this set. By the same argument also $u_\gamma > u_\beta$ in this set.

Therefore $u_\alpha > u_\beta$ for $t > 0, 0 < x < 1$.

Comment: Thank you, Hans Engler, for your excellent answer. My original target is a general two spatial dimensional parabolic equation. So there is first and zero'th order spatial partial derivatives. I was doing the same as you are doing with the spatial differentiation. However, for the general setting, with other orders of spatial derivatives present, I am not getting a clean PDE for $\partial^2_x u$ as is this simplified case with no zero'th and first order spatial derivatives.  I simplified the problem to this simple heat equation, because I later on suspected the conclusion was not true.

Comment: Good luck with your problem. Look also at work that cites Korevaar.

Comment: I am reading Korevaar paper you sent me. I have now posted a question in a more general  setting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207824/parabolic-equation-solution-dependence-on-parameters. Would you mind taking a look? I would like to look at the even more general two dimensional version later on if you would bear with me. Thank you, again, Hans Engler.

Comment: Should the Lemma add a condition that $\gamma″(x)\le 0$ for the maximum principle for parabolic equation with a zeroth order spacial derivative term used in the proof to hold? It seems there is no need for this restriction if the spatial domain is unbounded but if the solution is bounded exponentially by the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle. But here we have a bounded domain. What is the correct condition?